RSRQ and channel utilisation
I’m still a student trying to wrap my head around the basics of LTE Core etc..
I know that RSRQ is an indicator of the quality of the signal.
Are we able to gauge channel utilisation using RSRQ? (So I was thinking bad RSRQ could indicate channel congestion and if this statement is true, is it possible for RSRQ to be good but channel is congested and end devices are affected (slow internet connection, calls dont go through etc)
Thanks!!

RSRQ mostly tells you about interference from adjacent (or nearly adjacent) channels,  not congestion on the same channel.
It's entirely possible that you could have considerable channel congestion and the RSRQ would still look quite good.
